# Generate cut $(A,B)$ in edge-colored graph $(V,E_1 \cup E_2)$ such that there are more red than white crossings, i.e $|E_1(A,B)| > |E_2(A,B)|$

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, graph-algorithms, linear-programming, enumeration

Let $G=(V,E)$ be graph. Recall that a  cut of $G$ is (or can uniquely be identified with) a pair $(A,B)$ of nonempty subsets of $V$ which partition it. Given a cut $(A,B)$, let $E(A,B) := \{(a,b) \in E \mid a \in A, b \in B\} = E \cap (A \times B)$. Finally, let $E = E_1 \cup E_2$ be a given partitioning of the edges.

> **Question.** What is an efficient way to generate a cut $(A,B)$ of $G$ such that $|E_1(A,B)| > |E_2(A,B)|$ ?

**Note.** I'm fine with randomized algorithms. Also, in case one has the choice, I'd prefer a cut with minimal $|E(A,B)|$.

Comment: This problem may be NP-hard.  Suggest you edit your question to clarify how fast an algorithm you are looking for, and whether you would accept a proof of NP-hardness as an answer.

Comment: Ah, i felt it would be NP-hard, but didn't push it any further. Yes, I'd be fine with a transparent proof of NP-hardness.

Comment: BTW, would if one adds structural constraints like: $G$ is sparse or (in an appropriate sense) or with sufficiently uniform per-node degree, etc. Can anything be salvaged from the situation ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Theorem 1.** *The given problem is NP-hard, by reduction from MAX-CUT.*

*Proof.* Call the given problem Positive Discrepancy Cut (PDC).  Define *weighted PDC* to be the generalization where the input is a graph $G=(V,E)$ with polynomially bounded (possibly negative) integer edge weights, and the goal is to determine whether there is a positive-weight cut.  To prove the theorem we prove two lemmas:

**Lemma 1.** *Weighted PDC reduces in polynomial time to (unweighted) PDC.*

**Lemma 2.** *MAX-CUT reduces in polynomial time to Weighted PDC.*

*Proof of Lemma 1.* Given an $n$-vertex instance $G=(V,E)$ of weighted PDC with weights in $[-M, M]$, where $M$ is polynomial in $|G|$, the reduction outputs the graph $G'$ obtained from $G$ as follows.  Replace each vertex $v$ in $G$ by a clique $C_v$ of $|E|+1$ vertices, with all edges white.  For each edge $(u, v)$ of weight $w$ in $G$, add $|w|$ edges between $C_u$ and $C_v$, making them white if $w<0$ and red if $w>0$.  Given any positive-weight cut $(A, B)$ in $G$, the corresponding cut in $G'$ is $(A', B')$ where $A'= \bigcup_{v\in A} C_v$ and $B'=\bigcup_{v\in B} C_v$.  The number of red edges minus white edges crossing $(A', B')$ is the weight of the cut $(A, B)$.  So, if $G$ has a positive-weight cut, then $G'$ has a cut with more red than white edges.  Conversely, suppose $G'$ has a cut with more red than white edges.  The total number of red edges in $G'$ is at most $|E|M$, so each clique $C_v$ must be entirely contained in one side of the cut or the other.  So the cut corresponds to a cut in $G$ that has positive weight.  This proves Lemma 1. $~~\Box$

*Proof of Lemma 2.*  Given a MAX-CUT instance $(G=(V,E), k)$, the reduction outputs the instance $G'$ of Weighted PDC defined as follows.  Obtain $G'$ from $G$ by giving every edge in $G$ weight 1, then adding two vertex $a$ and $b$, each with edges to all other vertices.  Give each edge from $a$ or $b$ to a vertex in $G$ weight $-M$ where $M=|E|+1$.  Give the edge $(a, b)$ weight $M|V|-k+1$.  This completes the reduction.

Suppose there is a cut $(A, B)$ in $G$ with at least $k$ edges.  Then the cut $(A', B')$ in $G'$ where $A'=A \cup \{a\}$ and $B'=B\cup\{b\}$ has weight at least $k-|V|M + M|V|-k+1 = 1$.  Conversely, suppose there is a positive-weight cut $(A', B')$ in $G'$.  Vertices $a$ and $b$ cannot be on the same side of the cut, because if they are, the edge $(a, b)$ is not cut, while at least one edge out of $a$ or $b$ is cut, contributing $-M=-|E|-1$ to the cut weight, and each of the remaining edges (in $E$) contributes at most 1.  So $a$ and $b$ are on different sides of the cut $(A', B')$.  WLOG assume $a\in A'$ and $b\in B'$.  Then (accounting for the edges out of $a$ and $b$) the cut $(A, B)$ in $G$ where $A=A'\setminus \{a\}$ and $B=B'\setminus \{b\}$ must have at least $k$ edges.  So the reduction is correct. $~~\Box$

This reduction is similar to one by Peter Shor in [this answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/2318/8237) to a question about approximating MAX-CUT with negative edge weights.

Comment: Regarding your question above, I doubt that the problem is in P if you restrict to, say,  regular graphs with $O(1)$ degree.  No doubt MAX-CUT remains hard for such graphs, and I'd guess you can suitably modify the reduction above so that if the given MAX-CUT instance is regular with $O(1)$ degree, the reduction gives an instance of PDC that is sparse and regular.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, one easy case: if the graph has more red edges than white edges, there will be a vertex with more red edges than white edges incident to it, so that vertex alone will form a suitable cut.